# How can I translate this C++ function to C?

Tags: c

The code below is in C++. How do I translate it to C?

```
 void drawBoard()

    {
    system( "cls" );
    cout << "SCORE: " << score << endl << endl;
    for( int y = 0; y < 4; y++ )
    {
        cout << "+------+------+------+------+" << endl << "| ";
        for( int x = 0; x < 4; x++ )
        {
        if( !board[x][y].val ) cout << setw( 4 ) << " ";
        else cout << setw( 4 ) << board[x][y].val;
        cout << " | ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "+------+------+------+------+" << endl << endl;
    }
```

Comment: it's pretty much C compatible already, except `cout`s

Comment: so how do i fix the cout please

Comment: What type is `val` and `score` ?

Answer (score 1):

The code is pretty much C compatible already. However, the `cout`s are a C++ construct.

To make it fully C compatible, you could replace `cout` with `printf`. For instance, in your code,

```
cout << "SCORE: " << score << endl << endl; --> printf("SCORE: %d \n\n", score);
```

You'll have to play around with the different parameters to get the formatting and output right, but that's the general idea. A good reference is this site: [Printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `val` and `score` are `int`, the following lines:

```
cout << "SCORE: " << score << endl << endl;
cout << "+------+------+------+------+" << endl << "| ";
cout << setw( 4 ) << " ";
cout << setw( 4 ) << board[x][y].val;
```

would translate to:

```
printf("SCORE: %d\n\n", score);
printf("+------+------+------+------+\n| ";
printf("    ");
printf("%4d", board[x][y].val);
```

You can figure out the rest .